# virtualbox - Failed to load VMMR0.r0 (VERR_SUPLIB_WORLD_WRITABLE), unable to start virtual machines

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, genymotion

I have updated my ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS since then, I was unable to start my virtual machines and virtual box was showing this error. Struggled to solve it by trying various solutions. Finally solved it sharing to save someone's time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by changing permission for `/usr` as

```
chmod o-w /usr
```